# ffmpeg created timelapse won't play on other players than VLC

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am creating a Timelapse Video with the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -start_number 7754 -i IMG_%d.JPG -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 Output.mp4
```

This works without errors, but when I try to play the .mp4 on my Android Phone it shows an Error: "Unable to play file. Not enough resources"

With the VLC App:  "Currently unable to play this video. Stop the other video and try again"

When I put the Video through Handbrake It plays fine on all players.

I tried out changing some ffmpeg options, but nothing helped.

When I compare the output of `ffmpeg -i Output.mp4` from the original with the output from the video out of handbrake it differs only in the video bitrate.

Are there any other options I can try to change?

This is the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from 'PIC_%d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:02.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x56059fe911a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'ttyffmpeg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 2 fps, 16384 tbn, 2 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   56 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5242kB time=00:00:26.50 bitrate=1620.4kbits/s speed=5.38x    
video:5241kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.025511%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] frame I:9     Avg QP:14.75  size:111662
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] frame P:35    Avg QP:17.14  size: 90885
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] frame B:12    Avg QP:17.74  size: 98312
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] consecutive B-frames: 62.5% 21.4% 16.1%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] mb I  I16..4:  2.6% 96.8%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] mb P  I16..4:  1.0% 93.5%  1.2%  P16..4:  1.6%  1.1%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] mb B  I16..4:  0.6% 66.7%  2.1%  B16..8: 10.1% 10.6%  3.0%  direct: 4.8%  skip: 2.0%  L0:35.3% L1:34.6% BI:30.0%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] 8x8 transform intra:97.3% inter:91.2%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 94.3% 79.0% 44.3% inter: 77.2% 76.9% 31.3%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] i16 v,h,dc,p: 59% 25% 14%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 18% 42%  3%  2%  2%  4%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 27% 10%  3%  5%  5%  8%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] i8c dc,h,v,p: 40% 24% 29%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.6% UV:5.7%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] ref P L0: 67.0% 15.7% 14.0%  3.2%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] ref B L0: 88.0% 11.4%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x56059f9b4180] kb/s:1533.05
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Of what schall I share the log? From the Android players I can't get a log.

Comment: Of the ffmpeg command.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: This shows an output rate of 2 fps but your command indicates 24 fps. What's the result with 24 fps? Some players, like old versions of  VLC, don't work well with videos < 6 fps.

Comment: The framerate doesn"t matter. It changes nothing.