# Desktop recording with ffmpeg won't play in anything but VLC

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I'm creating a desktop application for fun/education. Its primary function is to record my PCs screen and have a pretty UI to play this back. I am recording with ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f gdigrab -framerate 50 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -r 50 -preset fast -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 23 "D:/vid.mp4"
```

At first glance this seems fine, a file is created and playing it back in VLC media player also works fine.

The problem is that I can't play this back in anything else. Windows apps  (videos + media player) just freeze up/provide no clue as to the problem. My end goal is to embed this into a HTML5 player to fit with the electron/react framework I'm writing my application in. This also doesn't play in a similar fashion.

I ran mediainfo on the file in WSL and got the following:

```
General
Complete name                            : vid.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 544 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 15 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 60.4 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf59.10.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High 4:4:4 Predictive@L4.2
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 min 15 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 60.3 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 2 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 50.000 FPS
Color space                              : RGB
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.581
Stream size                              : 543 MiB (100%)
Color range                              : Full
Matrix coefficients                      : Identity
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 1 min 15 s
Source duration                          : 1 min 15 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 132 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
```

I also saw this thread ([ffmpeg created timelapse won't play on other players than VLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889875/ffmpeg-created-timelapse-wont-play-on-other-players-than-vlc)) suggesting the bit rate may be the problem but having tried the suggestions there had no luck.

At a glance I suspected the "Codec ID" field as with comparison to other MP4 files that windows does play it is slightly different, i.e.:

`isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)` vs `mp42 (mp42/mp41/isom/avc1)`

However fiddling with the ffmpeg encoder settings I managed to vary this and still could not play the video back.

Also including the ffprobe output:

```
ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid.mp4:
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.10.100
  Duration: 00:01:15.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60414 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), gbrp(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60277 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gdigrab input is RGB. Video typically stores pixel data as YUV.

When saving to MP4 using a typical H.264 encoder, ffmpeg will convert to YUV color encoding but pick the highest fidelity pixel format which, for a RGB source, is YUV 4:4:4. This format is not compatible with most players. Solution is to manually force YUV 4:2:0 output. Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` just before the output filename.