# Using 'blend' filter with ffmpeg colors my video pink

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing, alphablending

I am using ffmpeg's library `fluent-ffmpeg` in nodejs.

My purpose is to blend a black box with text upon a video (using 'lighten' blend filter)
so the background will be deleted in a clean & beautiful way.

For some reason the video turns pink after I do that.

The code for blending:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
ffmpeg()
  .input(videoPath) // input '0', the background video
  .input(picturePath) // input '1', the black box with text
  .complexFilter([
    {
      filter: "blend",
      inputs: ["1", "0"],
      options: {
        all_mode: "lighten",
      },
    },
  ])

  .saveToFile(endPath)
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    reject(false);
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    resolve(true);
  });
```

Before the blend:

[image: Both video and picture before the blend]

After the blend:
[image: The resulted (undesired) video]

I've read [here](https://superuser.com/q/1546576) that the problem's cause may be that blend's format is `YUV` and not `GBRP`. I've tried it and it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. If possible, please give a code answer and not a command-line answer because converting it sometimes tends to do problems.

Comment: Have you tried to run the ffmpeg command from the terminal? Im not a fan of this wrapper libs since they do obfuscate the command they run. If it works from CLI, try to run the command with the node child_process module.

Comment: I did: `.\ffmpeg.exe -i "generated\vids\vid.mp4" -i ".\generated\images\img.png" -filter_complex "[1][0]blend=all_mode=lighten" test-video.mp4` gives the same result.

Comment: Could you post what the input frames both `vid.mp4` and `img.png`? (I'm not sure what the "before" pic is.) Also, any reason why you aren't using `overlay` with transparency instead of `blend`?

Comment: @kesh here are the video and image: https://imgur.com/a/1B0fIzc . How can I receive the same "deleting image background effect" with `overlay`?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I couldn't find a complete answer in the web I'll post one here in case anyone gets stuck here.

### The problem's cause

Video format `.mp4` as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72215220/12432147) gets encoded in `YUV`, which is not the way we are used to, with RGB pixels. Because of that, `lighten` blend don't work as I thought it would.

### Solution

1. Convert the video to `gbrp` format
2. Blend video with another video/image
3. Convert it back to `yuv420p format` (because most players can't read videos encoded in format `gbrp`)

CLI:

```
 .\ffmpeg.exe -i "generated\vids\vid.mp4" -i ".\generated\imgs\img.png" -filter_complex "[0]format=gbrp[vid];[1][vid]blend=all_mode=lighten[final];[final]format=yuv420p" test-video.mp4
```

Code (Javascript, via `fluent-ffmpeg`):

```
ffmpeg()
  .input(videoPath) // input '0'
  .input(imagePath) // input '1'
  .complexFilter(
    [
      { // Convert video to 'gbrp' format
        filter: 'format',
        inputs: ['0'],
        options: 'gbrp',
        outputs: 'vid'
      },
      { // Blend image on top of video
        filter: "blend",
        inputs: ["1", "vid"],
        options: {
          all_mode: "lighten",
        },
        outputs: 'final_video'
      },
      { // Convert video back to yuv420p format
        filter: 'format',
        inputs: ['final_video'],
        options: 'yuv420p',
      },

    ]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how to turn this into fluent-ffmpeg, but consider using the [`colorkey`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-colorkey) filter with the [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) filter. Something along the line of:

```
[1:v]colorkey=black[text];[0:v][text]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2
```

The colorkey filter turns the specified color transparent, so you can place its output right on the main video to get your desired effect. See the links above for other options.

Comment: I've already tried a similar way but it has problem with text that is not white. It doesn't look "clean" as if I would use blending filter. For example, look how grey text differs from blending to overlaying in [here.](https://imgur.com/a/kB9p2yG) The real question is... Why does it color the video pink. `lighten` according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Lighten_Only) should choose one of two pixels. It shouldn't bring new colors to the image....

Comment: ok. my guess on the pinkness is that the overlay image, which is smaller than the frame, is padded with white pixels so blending white and red gets you pink. What happens if you use `pad` filter to explicitly add black pixels to the overlay image the same size as the frame?

Comment: I've tried to blend [this](https://imgur.com/a/TZXD6Fh) picture and still same result. I've thought the same thing, but it keeps coloring it pink. From how I understand it, `lighten` shouldn't do `avg(color_a, color_b)` but `max(color_a, color_b)`. That's why I don't understand how there are new colors in the video. I guess it is the `YUV` format that it uses upon blending but I have no idea how should I change it. Maybe you, someone who understands more than me in ffmpeg for sure, knows how can I change the format.

Comment: How do I implement `Convert the video to a RGB pixel format using format=gbrp before feeding it to blend. At present, blend is acting upon a YUV input` in this CLI: `.\ffmpeg.exe -i "generated\vids\vid.mp4" -i ".\generated\imgs\img.png" -filter_complex "[1][0]blend=all_mode=lighten" test-video.mp4` `

Comment: exactly as the message says: `format=gbrp,blend=...`

Comment: I messed a bit with formats and came to a solution. Turns out we get the pink color because `lighten` in `YUV` format isn't the same as in `RGB` format. The math is probably different. Thanks!